# How to use Facebook's Extended Token with PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm developing a web site where the visitors will be able to login using their Facebook accounts. The lifetime of the default access token is a little too short - 2 hours - for my liking, which means that the user must login quite often. I therefore which to make use of an extended access token instead, with a lifetime of 60 days.

However, I can't get the setExtendedAccessToken method to work. When am I supposed to run it? On every page request? That doesn't seem right. Should I only call it after the user logged in, as they get redirected back from the Facebook login page?

Also, setExtendedAccessToken destroys the current session, which perhaps is the reason I can't get it to work...

I have tried to make a graph call to get the token like this:

```
$accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$graph_url   =  "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?";
$graph_url  .=  "client_id=".$facebookAppId;
$graph_url  .=  "&client_secret=".$facebookSecret;
$graph_url  .=  "&grant_type=fb_exchange_token";
$graph_url  .=  "&fb_exchange_token=".$accessToken;
$response   = @file_get_contents($graph_url);            
$params     = null;
parse_str($response, $params);
$extendedToken = $params['access_token'];
```

This way, I get an extended token, but what do I do with it? I have tried

```
$facebook->setAccessToken($extendedToken);
```

but that doesn't seem to do anything.

**UPDATE**

This is my latest version

```
if (isset($_GET["code"])) {
    $accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    $graph_url   =  "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?";
    $graph_url  .=  "client_id=".$facebookAppId;
    $graph_url  .=  "&client_secret=".$facebookSecret;
    $graph_url  .=  "&grant_type=fb_exchange_token";
    $graph_url  .=  "&fb_exchange_token=".$accessToken;

    $response = @file_get_contents($graph_url);      

    $params = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);
    $facebook->setAccessToken($params['access_token']);
}
```

This returns a valid extended token and seems to update the current token when I call setAccessToken. But the next time a reload the page, or any other page on the site, $facebook->getAccessToken returns a short lived token again.

**UPDATE 2**

I'm also using the Facebook Javascript SDK on the web site. Is it possible that this will interfere? Something like this:

1. Get new extended token on server
2. Update token on server
3. Success!
4. javascript replaces the newly fetched extended token with the regular short lived version
5. Fail

Comment: Do this `$facebook->setAccessToken($extendedToken);` after you fetched the extended token- just once. And the session is not destroyed. You are doing it in a right way, what problem are you facing?

Comment: Like I said in my update above, I'm passing the extended token to setAccessToken, but on next page load getAccessToken returns the short lived token again. I though it should be replaced, or do I have to call setAccessToken on every request?

Comment: No, not on every page. Did you debug the long lived token in [Debugger tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)?

Comment: Yes, and the long lived token looks OK, the problem seems to be that setAccessToken and getAccessToken doesn't care about the extended token.

Comment: Or rather that my graph call returns a new extended token, but never saves or updates the old token with the new one on Facebook's side.

Comment: Are you using `FB.login()` If not, then it will not interfere anything

Comment: Nope, I'm only using `FB.getLoginStatus`